# Work Visa Application Problem with Name?

Tags: germany, working-visas

My real name is (FN MN LN) :: "**Rita Daniel Matthews**" and the same name is reflected in all of my documents. Now my company is planning me to move to Germany (Europe) for some client project. But my passport has problem with my name. My passport has name as (FN MN LN) :: "**Rita Daneal Mathew**" this was due to my name printing mistake in Birth certificate issue by Indian Government. Please help me out to understand will I be able to apply for work visa? Will there be any problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably get your work permit application made out in the name listed on your passport, as that's your real name (as in, official).
I can call myself Jeremy, but that doesn't mean that becomes my real name, it's not the name I'm known to by any government agency...

But check with the agency responsible for issuing your paperwork, they're the ones who should know.

Comment: Great to here this Jeremy, i have mail Immigration dept. of my company. Soon after their reply i will accept answer. Thanks for reply

Comment: @RitaMatthews I don't actually call myself Jeremy, but I might :)